# Booting sidekiq: Error fetching message: ERR unknown command 'blpop'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I'm using Sidekiq for queue. When I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq` on my remote server, it gaves me the following errors, while the sidekiq runs well in local enviroment:

`2012-08-08T02:03:57Z 3348 TID-1hqs8u ERROR: Error fetching message: ERR unknown command 'blpop'`

`2012-08-08T02:03:57Z 3348 TID-1hqs8u ERROR: /home/deploy/www/zhule/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:79:in`call'
`

Local enviroment:

ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
Redis server version 2.4.15 (00000000:0)

Remote server enviroment:

ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
Redis server version 2.4.16 (00000000:0)

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I fixed this exact error by doing this: http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2012/07/err-unknown-command-blpop-for-resque-redis-and-rails/ but it looks like you're on the latest redis-already...

Comment: It works after i restarted the redis-server.